# How to use code inside #ifdef SHOUTCAST_METADATA

Tags: iphone, objective-c, streaming

I am using code of "Matt Gallagher" for streaming player

and there are some code inside

```
    #ifdef SHOUTCAST_METADATA
//Code 

    #endif
```

The system is not able to go inside these blocks.

Now currently the code inside is not working.....the code just needed to get the name of the stream playing.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this at the top of the file w/that `#ifdef`:

```
#define SHOUTCAST_METADATA 1
```

Of course, you'll need to deal with any dependencies incurred;  that code was compiled out for a reason.